# Reshaping large dataset in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I am trying to reshape a large dataset and have a problem not getting the results in the right order as I want to.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
GeoFIPS GeoName IndustryID  Description X2001   X2002   X2003   X2004   X2005 
10180   Abilene, TX     21  Mining      96002   92407   127138 150449   202926
10180   Abilene, TX     22  Utilities   33588   34116   33105   33265   32452
...
```

The dataframe is very long and includes all MSAs in the US with selected Industry sectors.

The way I wanted it to look like is this:

```
GeoFIPS GeoName        Year     Mining Utilities (etc)
10180   Abilene, TX    2001     96002   33588
10180   Abilene, TX    2002     92407   34116
....
```

I am pretty new to R and would really appreciate your help.
I have checked wide to long and long to wide, but this seems to be a more complex situation. 
Thank you!

Edit:
**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(GeoFIPS = c(10180L, 10180L), GeoName =
c("Abilene, TX", 
"Abilene, TX"), IndustryID = 21:22, Description = c("Mining", 
"Utilities"), X2001 = c(96002L, 33588L), X2002 = c(92407L, 34116L
), X2003 = c(127138L, 33105L), X2004 = c(150449L, 33265L), X2005 = 
c(202926L, 
 32452L)), .Names = c("GeoFIPS", "GeoName", "IndustryID", "Description", 
"X2001", "X2002", "X2003", "X2004", "X2005"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Please consider making your question reproducible. If you have data available there is no excuse not to include a small portion of it or alternatively simulate a small example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `melt/dcast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df1, id.var=c('GeoFIPS', 'GeoName', 
               'IndustryID', 'Description'))
df2 <- transform(df2, Year=sub('^X', '', variable))[-c(3,5)]


dcast(df2, ...~Description, value.var='value')
#  GeoFIPS     GeoName Year Mining Utilities
#1   10180 Abilene, TX 2001  96002     33588
#2   10180 Abilene, TX 2002  92407     34116
#3   10180 Abilene, TX 2003 127138     33105
#4   10180 Abilene, TX 2004 150449     33265
#5   10180 Abilene, TX 2005 202926     32452
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GeoFIPS = c(10180L, 10180L), GeoName =
c("Abilene, TX", 
"Abilene, TX"), IndustryID = 21:22, Description = c("Mining", 
"Utilities"), X2001 = c(96002L, 33588L), X2002 = c(92407L, 34116L
), X2003 = c(127138L, 33105L), X2004 = c(150449L, 33265L), X2005 = 
c(202926L, 
 32452L)), .Names = c("GeoFIPS", "GeoName", "IndustryID", "Description", 
"X2001", "X2002", "X2003", "X2004", "X2005"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```